# How to connect to development server in the cloud

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I can't connect to my MobileFirst server from my iOS native app.
I change the host, wlServerContext and port in my worklight.plist.
I upload the .wlapp and .adapter in the console of the server.

This is the log in my app:

```
2015-03-30 14:34:31.119 El_Universal_Demo[696:146217] Connecting to server and initializing push notification ...
2015-03-30 14:34:31.125 El_Universal_Demo[696:146217] [DEBUG] [WL_CONFIG] -[WLConfig init] in WLConfig.m:69 :: {
"application id" = "El_Universal_Demo";
"application version" = "1.0";
environment = iOSnative;
host = "198.11.212.197";
platformVersion = "7.0.0.0";
port = 8080;
protocol = http;
wlServerContext = "/wladmin";
wlUid = "wY/mbnwKTDDYQUvuQCdSgg==";
}
2015-03-30 14:34:31.160 El_Universal_Demo[696:146217] [WARN] [USER_CERT_AUTH] + [WLUserAuthManager getCertificateIdentifier] in WLUserAuthManager.m:68 :: Certificate Identifier Key:   com.worklight.userenrollment.certificate:com.eluniversal.El-Universal-Demo
2015-03-30 14:34:31.173 El_Universal_Demo[696:146217] [DEBUG]    [WL_AFHTTPCLIENTWRAPPER_PACKAGE] +[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestWithURL:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:46 :: Request url is http://198.11.212.197:8080/wladmin/apps/services/api/El_Universal_Demo/iOSnative/init
2015-03-30 14:34:31.202 El_Universal_Demo[696:146217] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:] in WLRequest.m:141 :: Request timeout is 60.000000
2015-03-30 14:34:31.206 El_Universal_Demo[696:146217] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:] in WLRequest.m:220 :: Sending request (http://198.11.212.197:8080/wladmin/apps/services/api/El_Universal_Demo/iOSnative/init) with headers: 
{
"Accept-Language" = es;
"User-Agent" = "El_Universal_Demo/1 (iPhone; iOS 8.1.2; Scale/2.00)/WLNativeAPI/7.0.0.0";
"X-Requested-With" = XMLHttpRequest;
"x-wl-app-version" = "1.0";
"x-wl-clientlog-appname" = "El_Universal_Demo";
"x-wl-clientlog-appversion" = "1.0";
"x-wl-clientlog-deviceId" = "A6042553-8580-4365-A69C-6731388D6A56";
"x-wl-clientlog-env" = iOSnative;
"x-wl-clientlog-model" = "iPhone6,1";
"x-wl-clientlog-osversion" = "8.1.2";
"x-wl-device-id" = "A6042553-8580-4365-A69C-6731388D6A56";
"x-wl-platform-version" = "7.0.0.0";
 }
 You can see the request body in the Analytics platform logs.
  2015-03-30 14:34:31.219 El_Universal_Demo[696:146217] [DEBUG]    [WL_AFHTTPCLIENTWRAPPER_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper start] in  WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:297 :: Starting the request with URL      http://198.11.212.197:8080/wladmin/apps/services/api/El_Universal_Demo/iOSnative/i nit
 2015-03-30 14:34:31.225 El_Universal_Demo[696:146217] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] __42-[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:]_block_invoke in WLRequest.m:230 :: waiting for response... (Thread=<NSThread: 0x17007f3c0>{number = 1, name = main})
 2015-03-30 14:34:31.231 El_Universal_Demo[696:146217] url a cargar (null)
 2015-03-30 14:34:31.288 El_Universal_Demo[696:146217] APNS Token : <9f662f33  5de5971b 5371851e 7d91fc17 f6f83d55 a9c913f6 973eec67 2e10c365>
 2015-03-30 14:34:31.289 El_Universal_Demo[696:146217] APNS Token : <9f662f33 5de5971b 5371851e 7d91fc17 f6f83d55 a9c913f6 973eec67 2e10c365>
 2015-03-30 14:34:31.476 El_Universal_Demo[696:146217] [DEBUG]   [WL_AFHTTPCLIENTWRAPPER_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestFailed:error:] in    WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:324 :: Request Failed
 2015-03-30 14:34:31.480 El_Universal_Demo[696:146217] [DEBUG]   [WL_AFHTTPCLIENTWRAPPER_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:325 :: Response Status Code : 404
 2015-03-30 14:34:31.484 El_Universal_Demo[696:146217] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPCLIENTWRAPPER_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:326 :: Response Error : Expected status code in (200-299), got 404
  2015-03-30 14:34:31.501 El_Universal_Demo[696:146217] [ERROR] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest requestFailed:error:] in WLRequest.m:466 :: Status code='404' error='Expected status code in (200-299), got 404' response=''
  2015-03-30 14:34:31.508 El_Universal_Demo[696:146217] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest requestFailed:error:] in WLRequest.m:469 :: Response Header: {
Connection = "Keep-Alive";
"Content-Language" = "en-US";
"Content-Length" = 0;
Date = "Mon, 30 Mar 2015 20:34:44 GMT";
"Keep-Alive" = "timeout=10, max=100";
"X-Powered-By" = "Servlet/3.0";
 }
Response Data: 
 2015-03-30 14:34:31.514 El_Universal_Demo[696:146217] [ERROR] [WL_CLIENT] - [WLClient onInitRequestFailure:userInfo:] in WLClient.m:1060 :: onInitRequestFailure
```

I need to test an example with notifications based on tags. My example works locally but I want to test it with the development server in the cloud and I cannot do that if my app doesn't connect.

I'm using MobileFirst 7.0

Regards.

Comment: is `wladmin` the name of your project? init path looks like `http://<host-name>:<port>/<project-name>/apps/services/api/<app-name>/<environment>/init`

Comment: wladmin is my server context root, and what I wanted to explain is that I have a native api project on iOS with push notifications based on tags and this is working on my local machine, but when I try to publish this in a public server on softlayer I can´t connect my app to the MFP server, I´ve changed the worklight.plist with the server parameters and it can´t connect to the server

Comment: And if you try w/out softlayer in your topology?

Comment: Idan what do you mean with w / out??

Comment: @A.Trejo w/out means without

Answer (score 0):

You say it's working locally. Can you expend on that?
Are you sure in the settings you've placed in worklight.plist?

```
http://198.11.212.197:8080/wladmin/apps/services/api/El_Universal_Demo/iOSnative/init
```

That IP address looks local to me rather than remote ("in the cloud"). Verify your settings.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, this problem was resolved.
I had to reinstall all the configuration of installation in my server and again upload the run time (.war), wlapp and adapter.

Also in the moment when I did the deploy of my native app in eclipse some times appeared an error in the console about a problem in the file .war.

So I had to make other workspace and verify settings of my native app. (worklight.plist)

My problem now is that I don´t receive any notification in my iPhone when I run a notification of my adapter but is other topic.

[1] [How to invoke the url or link of an adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29352183/how-to-invoke-the-url-or-link-of-an-adapter)

Regards